# Pytorch equivalent of tf.map_fn with parallel_iterations?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I'm executing a PyTorch function for n_iters times on a GPU. Currently I'm using a for loop for this. However, when n_iters is large, this is very inefficient. I'm wondering whether there is a PyTorch equivalent of tf.map_fn with the parallel_iterations functionality so that I can execute all the iterations in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched intensively and I was not able to find any function in pytorch thats equivalent to tf.map_fn that exposes number of parallel_iterations to be set by the user.

While exploring, I have found that there is a function named 'nn.DataParallel' but this function replicates the model or the operation that you want to run on multiple gpus and then returns the results which is not equivalent to **number of parallel_iterations** in tf.map_fn.

But for now in Pytorch, using the for loop is the only way to go right now.